# "withdrawn" message appears when launching vim

Tags: vim

I'm quite new to vim.

I'm trying tuning vim up by following a book about many tips and plugins of vim now.
I don't know since when it came to happen that when launching vim, it says:

```
$ vim
withdrawn
Press ENTER or type command to continue.
```

It soon disappear after pressing a certain key, and the :intro screen appear only for an instant, and soon it comes to an empty buffer. I'm confused, I just feel bad.
I googled on it but couldn't get a good result.

Why it happens? Is that caused by some plugin I installed recently? or of some weird act I did  but shouldn't have done?

I'm very beginner, so would someone tell me if there are ways to deal with it, please? I'd like the message to disappear, and the intro to come back.

Plugins I installed go like following(I'm using vundle):

```
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides.git'
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git'
Bundle 'Gist.vim'
Bundle 'ZenCoding.vim'
Bundle 'ref.vim'
Bundle 'unite.vim'
Bundle 'neocomplcache'
Bundle 'surround.vim'
Bundle 'kana/vim-textobj-user'
Bundle 'kana/vim-textobj-fold'
Bundle 'kana/vim-textobj-indent'
Bundle 'kana/vim-textobj-lastpat'
Bundle 'repeat.vim'
Bundle 'tomtom/tcomment_vim'
Bundle 'ManPageView'
Bundle 'autodate.vim'
Bundle 'rails.vim'
Bundle 'DrawIt'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Bundle 'taku-o/vim-toggle'
Bundle 'quickrun.vim'
Bundle 'buftabs'
Bundle 'bufexplorer.zip'
```

Most recent ones are DrawIt, buftabs, bufexplorer.
They might be doing something wrong.
I looked into ":help hit-enter", but couldn't understand well. It says looking "v:scrollstart"  is good, but I don't know how to look it.

I'm using Vim 7.3.353, and my laptop's OS is Mac OS X v10.7.2.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to find the source of it with such commands as `cd ~/.vim; ack withdrawn` (or, if you're not using `ack`, install it - you should! - or make do with `grep`)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan wow, I got it. ManPageView seemed to be withdrawn. Thanks so much!

Comment: OK then, I've turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the plugins will be doing it. Try to find the source of it with such commands as `cd ~/.vim; ack withdrawn` (or, if you're not using `ack`, install it—you should!—or make do with `grep`).

Answer (score 1):

The plugin essential for this message is "ManPageView".
Try commenting out the Bundle 'ManPageView' in your .vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get manpageview from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#MANPAGEVIEW .  It was withdrawn from vim.sf.net due to a bot blowing out the ratings.